# paypal sdk implementation in Swift UIKit

Tags: ios, swift, paypal

i am trying to implement Paypal SDK into my ios application, i am facing two problems first is i am not able to have Paylater button, even though i tried different parameters and second is does the implementation of pay later will be different than normal ? i am adding my effort so that you can help me find out issues.

```
func configurePayPalCheckout() {
      Checkout.setCreateOrderCallback { createOrderAction in
        let amount = PurchaseUnit.Amount(currencyCode: .mxn, value: "1500.00")
        let purchaseUnit = PurchaseUnit(amount: amount)
        let order = OrderRequest(intent: .capture, purchaseUnits: [purchaseUnit])
        createOrderAction.create(order: order)
      }

      Checkout.setOnApproveCallback { approval in
          
        approval.actions.capture { (response, error) in
          print("Order successfully captured: \(response?.data)")
        }
      }
    }
```

---

```
let paymentButton = PaymentButtonContainer()
      view.addSubview(paymentButton)

      NSLayoutConstraint.activate(
        [
          paymentButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: 200),
          paymentButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor)
        ]
      )
```

---

i am stuck with this for days now, i am sorry if its a noob question.

Answer (score 0):

Pay Later as its own button display is only available to payers with specific country and currency combinations. For example, USD and a US IP, GBP and UK (PayPal country code: "`GB`") IP, EUR and certain country IPs like DE, ES, FR, IT.

Currency MXN is not supported, IPs in MX are not supported.

---

For the web SDK which should be comparable you can test at https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server , changing the currency and using the sandbox-only SDK query string parameter `&buyer-country=US` , or similar. For some combinations `&enable-funding=paylater` also needs to be specified.

---

Separate from the button display, Pay Later may be available as a funding source to payers with a different IP once they log in to a PayPal checkout, if the currency matches. For example if the transaction is USD paid from an MX IP and a US payer signs in, they will see Pay Later as an option alongside credit card, etc.